# Is wake on LAN possible in Flex/AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, air, wake-on-lan

Title pretty much says it all... ;)

I'm looking for a way to allow my AIR application to wake a computer on my local network, but can't figure out how to send an UDP packet.

Of course I'm talking about an AS3/Flex/AIR solution, I know I could use NativeProcess but I'd like to stick with my multi-platform .air file.

I don't think AIR has support for broadcasting such UDP packets, but maybe someone will get an idea.
I don't know much about Alchemy, could it be of any help as it allows running C compiled code?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [DatagramSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html) class. Alchemy will not reveal hidden system capabilities for you, it's about transferring fast arythmetics into flash bytecode.

Comment: Well... "Note: Sending data to a broadcast address is not supported." =/
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html

Comment: That's all we got in AIR. It seems that without native helper answer to question is 'no'.

Comment: Seems like I'm always looking for things that cannot be done... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You could call a web service from Air

http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-web-service.aspx

Answer (score -2):

i see this question was posted a long time ago

in order to wake a computer, a magic packet needs to be sent over broadcast or directly to the machine IP.
The packet structure is :

mac address parsed as int
0xFF
16 times hex mac address

sent over udp with DatagramSocket

i made a small AS3 library for this, you can find it on my website.
https://nicopr.fr/1446603389-wake-on-lan-with-actionscript